# draft js(react js) decorators ,after 1000 words text background should be colored tweeter tweet box like

Tags: javascript, reactjs, text-editor, draftjs, draft-js-plugins

i have done it with decorators ,if i didn't enter while writing(creating new block) ,it works fine
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XchGi.png)

but when we text with new line decorator call as many time new line created and it didn't work please if anyone have solution please help ,thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10iBX.png)

my react component code below:

> import React, { useState, useRef } from "react"; import {   Editor,
> EditorState,   ContentState,   CompositeDecorator,   convertToRaw, }
> from "draft-js";
>
> const Decorated = ({ children }) => {   return {children}; };
>
> function findWithRegex(contentBlock, callback) {   const text =
> contentBlock.getText();   callback(1000, text.length > 1000 ?
> text.length : 1001); }
>
> const styles = {   editor: {
> // border: "1px solid gray",
> // minHeight: "6em",   }, };
>
> function handleStrategy(contentBlock, callback) {
> findWithRegex(contentBlock, callback); }
>
> const createDecorator = () =>   new CompositeDecorator([
> {
> strategy: handleStrategy,
> component: Decorated,
> },   ]);
>
> function TextArea(props) {   const [editorState, setEditorState] =
> useState(
> EditorState.createWithContent(
> ContentState.createFromText(props.value),
> createDecorator()
> )   );
>
> const editor = useRef(null);
>
> function focusEditor() {
> editor.current.focus();   }
>
> const onChnage = (editState) => {
> const blocks = convertToRaw(editState.getCurrentContent()).blocks;
> let value = blocks
> .map((block) => (!block.text.trim() && "\n") || block.text)
> .join("\n");
> setEditorState(editState);
> props.formik.setFieldValue(props.name, value !== "\n" ? value : "")   };
>
> React.useEffect(() => {
> focusEditor();   }, []);
>
> return (
>
>
>    ); }
>
> export default TextArea;

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i have provide component code ,you can use this component individualy